# how could I fix publishupdate method of Asynctask class

Tags: android, android-asynctask, custom-adapter

I'm implementing a network scanner. which pings an ip address. If ping is returned then create Node using Node class. However, when try to use publishupdate method in doinbackground() I'm getting errors. Also, onprogressupdate() method says not override superclass. What's wrong with the implementation. I'm reading the documentation, but can't figure it out. Any help appreciated. Thanks

```
package com.example.android.droidscanner;

import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by jlvaz on 3/1/2017.
 */

public class IpScanActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String ip;
    String mac;
    ArrayList<Node> hostList;
    ListView networkScan;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.scan_list);

        hostList = new ArrayList<>();

        //inflating adapter
        networkScan  = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.scan_list);
        NodeAdapter networkAdapter = new NodeAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, hostList);
        networkScan.setAdapter(networkAdapter);

        //scanning network
        TaskScanNetwork scanNetwork = new TaskScanNetwork();
        scanNetwork.execute();



    }

    /*
       * AscynTask to scan the network
       * you should try different timeout for your network/devices
       * it will try to detect localhost ip addres and subnet. then
       * it will use subnet to scan network
       *
       */
    private class TaskScanNetwork extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

        String localIp;
        String mac;
        String subnet;
        static final int lower = 1;
        static final int upper = 254;
        static final int timeout = 1000;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            WifiManager wifiMan = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
            WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiMan.getConnectionInfo();
            int ipAddress = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
            localIp  = String.format("%d.%d.%d.%d", (ipAddress & 0xff),(ipAddress >> 8 & 0xff),(ipAddress >> 16 & 0xff),(ipAddress >> 24 & 0xff));
            subnet = ip.substring(0, ip.lastIndexOf("."));
            hostList.clear();
            //textResult.setText("Scanning Network...");
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            for (int i = lower; i <= upper; i++) {
                String host = subnet + "." + i;
                Log.v("Host: ", host);

                try {
                    InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(host);
                    if (inetAddress.isReachable(timeout)) {
                        Node newNode = new Node(host);
                        publishProgress(newNode);
                    }

                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Node... values) {
            hostList.add(values[0]);
            networkScan.deferNotifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            //result.setText("Live Hosts: ");
        }
    }

}
```

Node Class

```
package com.example.android.droidscanner;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

/**
 * Created by george on 2/14/17.
 */

public class Node {
    String ip;
    String mac;
    String CanonicalHostName;
    String HostName;
    String remark;
    boolean isReachable;

    Node(String ip){
        this.ip = ip;
        //this.mac = mac;
        this.isReachable = true;
    }

    public String getIp() {
        return ip;
    }

    public String getHostName() {
        return HostName;
    }

    public String getMac() {
        return mac;
    }

    public String getRemark() {
        return remark;
    }

    public boolean isReachable() {
        return isReachable;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "IP: " + ip + "\n" +
                "MAC: " + mac + "\n" +
                "CanonicalHostName:\t" + CanonicalHostName + "\n" +
                "HostName:\t" + HostName + "\n" +
                "isReachable: " + isReachable +
                "\n" + remark;
    }

    private void queryHost(){
        try {
            InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
            CanonicalHostName = inetAddress.getCanonicalHostName();
            HostName = inetAddress.getHostName();

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            remark = e.getMessage();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            remark = e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

NodeAdapter class

```
public class NodeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Node>{

    public NodeAdapter(Context context, int num, ArrayList<Node> allHost) {
        super(context, 0, allHost);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        Node host = getItem(position);
        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }
        // Lookup view for data population
        TextView nodeIpTxtView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.node_ip);
        TextView nodeMacTxtView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.node_mac);
        // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
        nodeIpTxtView.setText(host.getIp());
        nodeMacTxtView.setText(host.getMac());
        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By errors, I presume you mean compile errors.  `AsyncTask` is a generic type that defines a number of generic parameters.  Think of the the definition as follows:

```
AsyncTask<BACKGROUND, PROGRESS, POST_EXECUTE>
```

You currently have:

```
AsyncTask<Void, String, Void>
```

So you're saying:

- on background pass my method `Void`
- on progress pass my method `String`
- on post execute pass my method `Void`

However, your `onProgressUpdate` method is expecting a `Node` type.  So change your definition of the `TaskScanNetwork` to:

```
private class TaskScanNetwork extends AsyncTask<Void, Node, Void> {
```

There's also a good example and explanation here. Apologies if you have seen this already:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#AsyncTask()

Comment: np - don't forget to accept if this answer works for you :)